# How to list all the notes from an Evernote notebook - Javascript / Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote

I set up my node.js / express app to work with Evernote api using their sdk.

Now I need to get a list of all the notes from a notebook.

I successfully get a list of the notebooks using this code:

```
 var client = new Evernote.Client({token: req.session.oauthAccessToken});
    var noteStore = client.getNoteStore();
    notebooks = noteStore.listNotebooks(function(err, notebooks) {
        console.log(notebooks);
 });
```

Does anyone know how I could amend it to get the list of all the notes from a particular Notebook for which I know GUID?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried `noteStore.getNotebook(req.session.oauthAccessToken, [GUID]);`?

Comment: It seems to be very difficult to find official usable simple samples that do basic things with the evernote API. The samples I have seen are incomplete, and don't do things like this.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code that should work.  Just change notebook.guid to the guid of the notebook you need:

```
    //create filter for findNotesMetadata
    filter = new Evernote.NoteFilter();
    //set the notebook guid filter to the GUID of the default notebook
    filter.notebookGuid = notebook.guid; //change this to the GUID of the notebook you want
    //create a new result spec for findNotesMetadata
    resultSpec = new Evernote.NotesMetadataResultSpec();
    //set the result spec to include titles
    resultSpec.includeTitle=true;
    //call findNotesMetadata on the note store
    noteStore.findNotesMetadata(filter, 0, 100, resultSpec, function(err, notesMeta) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('err',err);
        }
        else {
          //log the number of notes found in the default notebook
          console.log("Found "+notesMeta.notes.length+" notes in your default notebook . . .")
          for (var i in notesMeta.notes) {
            //list the title of each note in the default notebook
            console.log(i+": "+notesMeta.notes[i].title);
          }


        }});
```

Keep in mind [findNotesMetadata](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) returns a [metadataList](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NotesMetadataList) and not an actual list of notes.  You'll need to download each note via [getNote](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote) if you need the content but check the [resultsSpec](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NotesMetadataResultSpec) attributes for other data you might need before you call getNote for each note as much of the data you might need can be retrieved via the [findNotesMetadata](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata) method.

Here is a fully working (once you add your [developer token](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/authentication.php)) code sample that retrieves all the notes from the default notebook and logs the titles of the notes:

```
  Evernote = require('evernote').Evernote;

  var authToken = "your developer token";

  if (authToken == "your developer token") {
    console.log("Please fill in your developer token");
    console.log("To get a developer token, visit https://sandbox.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action");
    process.exit(1);
  }

  var client = new Evernote.Client({token: authToken, sandbox: true});

  var userStore = client.getUserStore();
  var noteStore = client.getNoteStore();

  var notebook=noteStore.getDefaultNotebook(function (err, notebook){
    //create filter for findNotesMetadata
    filter = new Evernote.NoteFilter();
    //set the notebook guid filter to the GUID of the default notebook
    filter.notebookGuid = notebook.guid;
    //create a new result spec for findNotesMetadata
    resultSpec = new Evernote.NotesMetadataResultSpec();
    //set the result spec to include titles
    resultSpec.includeTitle=true;
    //call findNotesMetadata on the note store
    noteStore.findNotesMetadata(filter, 0, 100, resultSpec, function(err, notesMeta) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('err',err);
        }
        else {
          //log the number of notes found in the default notebook
          console.log("Found "+notesMeta.notes.length+" notes in your default notebook . . .")
          for (var i in notesMeta.notes) {
            //list the title of each note in the default notebook
            console.log(i+": "+notesMeta.notes[i].title);
          }


        }}); 

  });
```

sample output:

```
  Found 3 notes in your default notebook . . .
  0: This is a test note!
  1: Hello Developer Forums!!!
  2: How are you doin'?
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the findNotesMetadata method with a filter. Take a look at the doc : 
http://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_findNotesMetadata

The code should be something like this (not tested. But it'll give you the idea.):

```
var mynotebook = notebooks[0];
var filter = new NoteFilter();
var resultSpec = new resultSpec();

# this determines which info you'll get for each note
resultSpec.includeTitle  = true
resultSpec.includeContentLength = true
resultSpec.includeCreated = true
resultSpec.includeUpdated = true
resultSpec.includeDeleted = true
resultSpec.includeUpdateSequenceNum = true
resultSpec.includeNotebookGuid = true
resultSpec.includeTagGuids = true
resultSpec.includeAttributes = true
resultSpec.includeLargestResourceMime = true
resultSpec.includeLargestResourceSize = true

filter.notebookGuid = mynotebook.guid;
notes = noteStore.findNotesMetadata(authToken, filter, 0, 10, resultSpec);
```